# Lumen prevent duplicate job in a queue

Tags: php, laravel-8, jobs, lumen

Using `lumen 8.2.3` I am only trying to dispatch a unique job to a queue. In app/Console/Kernel I have sent a schedule to  `$schedule->job(new myJob(), 'high')->everyMinute();` this runs every minutes.
In the job itself I have added the `ShouldBeUnique` interface class in `myJob class` I even added

```
public function uniqueId() { 
   return $this->process->id();
}
```

when my cron job runs for `php artisan schedule:run`, this is still creating multiple jobs in the queue causing my 3 workers to pick up both jobs at the same time and causing issues.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#unique-jobs clearly says

> "Sometimes, you may want to ensure that only one instance of a
> specific job is on the queue at any point in time. You may do so by
> implementing the ShouldBeUnique interface on your job class. This
> interface does not require you to define any additional methods on
> your class:"

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Throwable;

class myJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    private $process;

    public function __construct($process){
       $this->process=$process;
    }
    public function uniqueId() { 
       return $this->process->id();
    }
    
    
    public function handle()
    {
       //some code here
    }

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
    // Send user notification of failure, etc...
    }
  }
```

Is the no way to prevent this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

odd how this got fixed but what I did was change the version from `8.2.4` to `8.3.4` and `shouldBeUnique` work looks like a bug was introduced in 8.3.4

Answer (score 0):

The code provided barely reflects what you are writing; there's no job at all.

The declaration should look like this:

```
class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, Dispatchable;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have updated the question to show my code structure. 

`Trait "Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable" not found` lumen 8.2.3 does not have this traits. Is this important to making this work?